# Get contents of a map as an array

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, std

I have a `std::map` of `HANDLE` objects,
`std::map<int, HANDLE> MyMap;`

I have to wait on these handle objects using WaitForMultipleObjects() function. For that i have to get the map contents as an array of HANDLE objects.(if it was a vector, then we can use vector.data() function). And I am looking for such a simple function to achieve this.

Comment: So, You are saying that to use an intermediate vector to keep all the handle objects from the map. right?

Comment: Are you looking for something over creating a new vector and adding all handles to it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're using a reasonably recent version of VC++ (2010 or 2012), or g++ (4.6 or newer), you should be able to do something like this:

```
std::vector<HANDLE> handles;

std::transform(your_map.begin(), your_map.end(),
    std::back_inserter(handles),
    [](std::pair<const int, HANDLE> const &i) { return i.second; });
```

Comment: If you change that lambda argument to `std::pair<const int, HANDLE> const &i`, or `std::map<int, HANDLE>::value_type const &i`, you can save an unnecessary copy.  I only mention it because it seemed like you were trying to save a copy anyway by taking a const reference.

Comment: Can I use iterator for this. means , iterating through all the values and push_back that values into a handle vector?

Answer (score 1):

- Reserve the space in the vector based on the size of the map. See 'std::vector::reserve' member.
- Use std::copy and std::back_inserter.